Go through a line of code and get the course name, crn, days and time and output it
Structures of Computer Science         10916       Mon, Thu            8:30 AM
Computer Science I Lab                 49835        Tue                 1:00 PM

The name of the course is separated by space, then there's a tab, a 5-digit crn, the days could be two or one (if two, separated by a comma and space), then a tab, then the time, the hour, a colon, the min, space then the time of day (AM or PM).
There's a file with a bunch of these, each line has a course description (name), the five digit crn, and meeting days and time. I want to write code to get all of any and output like this:
Description: Structures of Computer Science
CRN: 10916
Meeting Days: Mon, Thu
Meeting Time: 8:30 AM

Sometimes there is only one meeting day.
I have something like this but it fails:
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Function to parse the line and extract relevant information
void parseLine(const string& line) {
    stringstream ss(line);
    string token;
    vector<string> tokens;
    
    // Split the line into tokens
    while (ss >> token) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    
    // Output the relevant information
    if (tokens.size() >= 4) {
        // Extract the description
        string description;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < tokens.size() - 3; ++i) {
            description += tokens[i];
            if (i < tokens.size() - 4) {
                description += " ";
            }
        }
        
        // Extract CRN
        string crn = tokens[tokens.size() - 3];
        
        // Extract meeting days
        string meetingDays = tokens[tokens.size() - 2];
        
        // Extract meeting time
        string meetingTime = tokens[tokens.size() - 1];
        
        // Output parsed information
        cout << "Description: " << description << endl;
        cout << "CRN: " << crn << endl;
        cout << "Meeting Days: " << meetingDays << endl;
        cout << "Meeting Time: " << meetingTime << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid input line!" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    string line = "Structures of Computer Science          10916       Mon, Thu            8:30 AM";
    
    // Parse and output information
    parseLine(line);
    
    return 0;
}

The output I get is this:
Description: Structures of Computer Science 10916 Mon,
CRN: Thu
Meeting Days: 8:30
Meeting Time: AM


I think it would be easier to go backwards through the tokens. Get the last two for the time, then get tokens until you get one that is a number for the days, then the number itself for the CRN, and lastly the rest for the name.

You can't use operator>> to read tokens that are separated by tabs, since tabs are whitespace. You can use std::getline() instead with the delimiter set to '\t to read the tokens.

@Someprogrammerdude Elements are TAB-delimited, so that kind of effort is unnecessary here. If everything were spaces, then yeah, life would get harder. (OP’s example text has no TABs, I know...)


// Split the line into tokens
while (ss >> token) {
    tokens.push_back(token);
}


You can't use operator>> to read fields separated by tabs, since tabs are whitespace that operator>> ignores, same as spaces.  In your example, the 1st line contains 9 tokens, and the 2nd line contains 8 tokens. Your parsing code has no way of knowing which token belongs to which field.
To read tab-separated strings, you can use std::getline() instead with its delimiter set to '\t', eg:
void parseLine(const string& line) {
    istringstream ss(line);
    string token;
    vector<string> tokens;
    
    // Split the line into tokens
    while (getline(ss, token, '\t')) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }

    // Output the relevant information
    if (tokens.size() >= 4) {
        // Extract the description
        string description = tokens[0];
        
        // Extract CRN
        string crn = tokens[1];
        
        // Extract meeting days
        string meetingDays = tokens[2];
        
        // Extract meeting time
        string meetingTime = tokens[3];
        
        // Output parsed information
        cout << "Description: " << description << endl;
        cout << "CRN: " << crn << endl;
        cout << "Meeting Days: " << meetingDays << endl;
        cout << "Meeting Time: " << meetingTime << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid input line!" << endl;
    }
}

Online Demo

Use C++ idioms to help you out.
#include <ciso646>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Use a `struct` to group related information
//
struct CourseInfo
{
    std::string name;
    std::string CRN;
    std::string days;
    std::string time;
};

// Write a "stream extraction operator" to parse course info.
//
// You could, of course, instead name your function something like:
//   bool parseLine( std::istream & ins, CourseInfo & ci );
//
// But this way is the idiomatic C++ way, and makes life easier in all kinds of ways.
//
std::istream & operator >> ( std::istream & ins, CourseInfo & ci )
{
    // Skip all leading whitespace and read a line from the file.
    std::string s;
    if (!getline( ins >> std::ws, s )) return ins;

    // Tokenize the line into its TAB-delimited parts
    // Since everything is a string, no further processing is required
    // than simple read and save.
    std::istringstream ss( s );
    getline( ss, ci.name, '\t' );
    getline( ss, ci.CRN,  '\t' );
    getline( ss, ci.days, '\t' );
    getline( ss, ci.time, '\t' );

    // Make sure to report any errors to the argument stream (`ins`)
    if (!ss or !ss.eof())
        ins.setstate( std::ios::failbit );

    return ins;
}

int main()
{
    // Here is our input file. 
    // (We'll use a stringstream instead of an external file for convenience.)
    std::istringstream courses_file
    {
        "Structures of Computer Science\t" "10916\t" "Mon, Thu\t" "8:30 AM\n"
        "Computer Science I Lab\t"         "49835\t" "Tue\t"      "1:00 PM\n" 
    };

    // Let's read the file into vector
    std::vector <CourseInfo> courses;
    {
        CourseInfo course_info;
        while (courses_file >> course_info)
            courses.push_back( course_info );
    }
    
    // And print out our vector data
    for (const auto & course : courses)
        std::cout
            << "Description: "  << course.name << "\n"
            << "CRN: "          << course.CRN  << "\n"
            << "Meeting Days: " << course.days << "\n"
            << "Meeting Time: " << course.time << "\n\n";
    std::cout << courses.size() << " courses total.\n";
}

EDIT: I meant to add that doing things like this decouples reading the course information from other tasks, like printing the course information. You could certainly do both (for example, the code above need not use the vector, just read and print in the loop!).

I believe you can avoid the temporary variable by constructing your vector from a pair of iterators, as described here; and actually, you could probably forego the vector altogether: using iterator = std::istreambuf_iterator<CourseInfo>; for auto course : std::make_iterator_range(iterator{courses_file}, iterator{}) { /* etc. */ };  but then - perhaps this is already burdening OP with too much already.

Avoiding the vector and temporary values is beyond the scope of this Q&A. (And there is nothing weird or unusual with using a temporary for stuff like this! That’s premature optimization IMHO.)

Agreed, but exactly by that logic, I believe @RemyLebeau provided the best answer, in that he only suggested a fix for the bug rather than a complete rewrite.

That is why you should upvote his answer.
